# RoR - Images in DB tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing

I want a user to upload multiple images (+ thumbs) and give a description about their pics.

What do i need to do to create this the ruby way?
Do i manually create the tables (and which are these) or what gem do i require?

I want to store the file physical on a path and store the link (+ attr. information) in the db (if it is the best solution).

I am open to any alternatives to seek my best solution! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [paperclip](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip). Other great solution for handling multiple images for an item is [paperclippolymorph](http://github.com/heavysixer/paperclippolymorph)

Comment: where do i store the description values for these images?

Comment: I'm not so proficient with 'em, simply I know this is solution many of friends use

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a "best" solution, whether or not you store the images in the database is a tradeoff.  Storing images on the server's filesystem and keeping the file's path information in the database will keep your DB smaller, but it will also add one more folder/location that you need to keep backed up and can provide security problems (if the image storage folder is not properly secured, it can be easier for an attacker to pull images off of a filesystem than extract them out of a database).